# containerized .NET Core 2.2 docker build fails in VS but works in CLI

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

After deploying and debugging orchestrated microservice-containers in Visual Studio 2019 for several days without problems, all of a sudden, one microservice did not build correctly anymore:

While the build process does not throw an error, the app in the container will not start anymore because of (if I shell into the container and try to start it manually):

```
root@05dd00f151aa:/app/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2# dotnet xxx.dll
realpath(): Invalid argument
realpath(): Invalid argument
realpath(): Invalid argument
realpath(): Invalid argument
realpath(): Invalid argument
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (xxx.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'AspNetCore.HealthChecks.AzureServiceBus', version: '2.2.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/HealthChecks.AzureServiceBus.dll'
```

The weird thing is that if I build and deploy the containers manually by

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up
```

all works fine...
I also completely reset the git repo - and with my colleagues this problem does not come up at all...

I have been trying to fix this for days now, including deleting all images, resetting Docker Desktop to factory defaults, cloning the repo into a new folder, all without success...

Anyone encountered something alike once already?

Comment: So, error resolves if I run VS as administrator... What could this be?

Comment: Problem came back, also not working when running as admin anymore...